# Salesforce Metadata API - Easy Way To Get Entity Relationships / Joins?

Tags: metadata-api, relationships, schema, describes

Is anyone aware of something free, that already exists, that can comb output from the Metadata API and output useful information about joins between tables?

I just wrote my colleagues the following e-mail:

> Right now, as I understand it, it’s relatively easy to dump the
>   schemas & contents of a bunch of Salesforce tables into Cognos
>   Framework Manager as raw data.  (After all, we've already done it.)
>
> But telling Cognos Framework Manager how to re-connect those tables to
>   each other - in ways that replicate the ways they're connected to each
>   other in Salesforce - is extremely manual (click-and-configure).  Plus
>   it involves actually knowing those relationships as they stood in
>   Salesforce.
>
> However, it looks like Salesforce and Framework Manager both have "Metadata
>   APIs."
>
> In theory, code could be written that:
>
> 1. Extracts a
>      schema of “table joins” from Salesforce
> 2. Transforms those joins into
>      something that Framework Manager would understand
> 3. Loads a bunch of
>      useful pre-joined views into a Cognos package (without ever having to
>      open the GUI version of Framework Manager)
>
> Right now, I think we're mostly in a paradigm "do your own joins using
>   Cognos Report Studio at report-making time."
>
> And right now, that approach probably consumes fewer staff-hours than
>   doing inter-API programming.  (See XKCD's
>   "automation" theory:  https://xkcd.com/1319/)
>
> But if that workload balance ever starts to shift to the tipping point
>   of "this would be worth automating," it looks like it may be able to
>   be done.

If "step 1" *("**extract a schema of 'table joins'**")* has already been done, or significant progress towards it has been made, that'd help reduce the scope of the work a lot.

Does anyone know if others have already blazed such a trail?

---

**Updated question:**

**Q:**  *If* my "destination" API just wants 2 fully-qualified base-table field names, "TableReferredTo.Id" & "TableReferring.ForeignKeyFieldName," to set up a join, *then I'm done, right*?  Shouldn't I be able to just iterate through the lower level of this Python dict issuing "create join" API calls?

Code Example (Python):

```
import os, fnmatch
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = '{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}'

objdumppath = 'C:\\temp\\dumpeddata\\'
objapis = [f.rstrip('object').rstrip('.') for f in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(objdumppath), '*.object')]

relationshipsdict = {}

for o in objapis:
    tablefields = ET.parse(objdumppath+o+'.object').getroot().findall(ns+'fields')
    relationshipsdict[o] = {}
    for f in tablefields:
        if f.find(ns+'fullName') != None and f.find(ns+'referenceTo') != None and f.find(ns+'type') != None and f.find(ns+'type').text in ['MasterDetail','Lookup']:
            fieldFullName = f.find(ns+'fullName').text
            fieldType = f.find(ns+'type').text
            fieldRefersTo = f.find(ns+'referenceTo').text
            #relationshipsdict[o+'.'+fieldFullName] = {'fieldFKType' : fieldType, 'tableReferredTo' : fieldRefersTo}
            relationshipsdict[o][fieldFullName] = {'fieldFKType' : fieldType, 'tableReferredTo' : fieldRefersTo}
```

Printed out pretty, the nested-dicts look kind of like this:

```
-----Object "Employment_History__c" and its foreign-key fields:-----
{
    'Appl__c':  
            {   'fieldFKType': 'MasterDetail',
                'tableReferredTo': 'SpecialPkg__Application__c'
            }
}
-----Object "SpecialPkg__Supplemental_Doc__c" and its foreign-key fields:-----
{
    'SpecialPkg__Appl__c':
            {
                'fieldFKType': 'Lookup',
                'tableReferredTo': ' SpecialPkg__Application__c '
            },
     'SpecialPkg__Other_Contact__c':
            {
                'fieldFKType': 'Lookup',
                'tableReferredTo': 'Contact'
            }
}
-----(and so on...)-----
```

Or, built differently (no outer-loop dict addition, and change inner-loop dict addition to `relationshipsdict[o+'.'+fieldFullName] = {'fieldFKType' : fieldType, 'fieldReferredTo' : fieldRefersTo+'.'+'Id'}`), more like:

```
-----Employment_History__c.Appl__c-----
{'fieldFKType': 'MasterDetail', 'fieldReferredTo': 'SpecialPkg__Application__c.Id'}

-----SpecialPkg__Supplemental_Doc__c.SpecialPkg__Appl__c-----
{'fieldFKType': 'Lookup', 'fieldReferredTo': 'SpecialPkg__Application__c.Id'}

-----SpecialPkg__Supplemental_Doc__c.SpecialPkg__Other_Contact__c-----
{'fieldFKType': 'Lookup', 'fieldReferredTo': 'Contact.Id'}

-----(and so on...)-----
```

Comment: You can certainly parse the schema yourself using describes...what are you trying to accomplish? Do you really need to see every object?

Comment: Yes, potentially "all of them" - the idea is to have "every table in Salesforce" available for easy reporting through a different tool.  So, the goal is to parse a given dump of objects and build an entity-relationship model of their interconnections.

Comment: Is visual representation good enough? There's `Schema Builder`...

Comment: Nope.  Needs to be textual so it can be transformed into calls against the destination tool's model-building API.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to build anything that can be serialized, since you cannot avoid the possibility of circular references.

Comment: Hmmm...am I really the first person to dream up a program that serializes database relationships based on a schema, for loading into another schema-building tool?  That problem has to have been addressed before...  (Maybe leave yourself breadcrumbs & stop if you run into the same object more than once/twice, deciding that 95% of relationships is "close enough"...)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a simple mapping of which objects are related to which others, you could roll your own naive implementation fairly simply. You could even hook it up to a `REST` service. Just for fun...

```
public with sharing class SchemaModel
{
    final Map<SObjectType, Set<SObjectType>> model;
    public SchemaModel(List<SObjectType> sObjectTypes)
    {
        model = new Map<SObjectType, Set<SObjectType>>();
        for (SObjectType sObjectType : sObjectTypes)
            model.put(sObjectType, new Set<SObjectType>());
        for (SObjectType sObjectType : sObjectTypes)
            addRelationships(sObjectType);
    }
    void addRelationships(SObjectType sObjectType)
    {
        for (SObjectField field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
            addRelationships(sObjectType, field.getDescribe().getReferenceTo());
    }
    void addRelationships(SObjectType sourceType, List<SObjectType> referenceTo)
    {
        for (SObjectType targetType : referenceTo)
            if (model.containsKey(targetType))
                model.get(sourceType).add(targetType);
    }

    public override String toString()
    {
        Map<String, Set<String>> simpleModel = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
        for (SObjectType key : model.keySet())
            simpleModel.put(String.valueOf(key), getRelationships(key));
        return JSON.serialize(simpleModel);
    }
    Set<String> getRelationships(SObjectType key)
    {
        Set<String> referenceTo = new Set<String>();
        for (SObjectType targetType : model.get(key))
            referenceTo.add(String.valueOf(targetType));
        return referenceTo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adrian!  Was simultaneously working on the same "this points to that" idea in Python; updated original question.  I guess now my only question left is ... "**Was I overthinking this at time of OP**?"  _(Is a textual entity-relationship model, for the purposes of migrating the "relationships," probably nothing but a list of "all arrow-tails and their corresponding arrow-heads, plus some TailCanBeNull metadata about each"?)_

Comment: Um, what? If you want to store all the fields it certainly gets more complicated. Your model in the updated question is flawed because some lookups are polymorphic, so `tableReferredTo` would need to be plural.

Comment: Completely forgot about polymorphic fields - thank you!